# Why isn't the limit in the derivative's definition always equal to zero?

Tags: limits

[image]

In the image linked above you can see what I mean. I get that it's not right and not supposed to be done, but I'm trying to understand why.

Also, why is it instead allowed to do this:

[image]

If the answer is obvious, feel free to call me an idiot.

Appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: $0 \cdot \infty$ is an inteterminate expression. In general, you can't assign it a value. If you encounter such an expression, it's usually a sign that you need to reorganize the previous expression.

Comment: in addition to the above comment, limit of product is not necessarily product of limits.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Your mistake is the statement $0 \cdot \infty = 0$, which is incorrect. In fact the expression makes no sense - different answers are possible in different situations.

Comment: Both Bungo and Vasya bring up correct objections

Comment: To gain an insight as to why the limit cannot always be distributed over a product, study the proof of the theorem that says that it CAN be done, given certain hypotheses. You will see how the proof doesn't work without those hypotheses.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I know now what the mistake was. Didn't expect such a quick response, loving this community already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some others have mentioned, you can split the limit of a product as a product of limits only in certain cases, one of which is when the limit exists. In the first case you gave, you implied that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} = \infty$$

However, this is incorrect. The limit as $h$ tends to 0 from the right is positive infinity, but from the left it is negative infinity. Since the limits from both ends are different, the limit does not exist, so you can't split the product.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(h)g(h)=\left(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(h)\right)\left(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}g(h)\right)$$

ONLY when the individual limits exist, this is called the algebra of limits.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that $0\times\infty=0$. Actually, $\times$ is defined only for numbers. Therefore, $0\times\infty$ is undefined.

On the other hand, as far as limits are concerned, if $\lim_{h\to0}f(h)=0$ and if $\lim_{h\to0}g(h)=\infty$, then the limit $\lim_{h\to0}f(h)g(h)$ may not exist and, if it does exist, it can be anyting. For instance, if $f(h)=kh$ and $g(h)=\frac1h$, then $\lim_{h\to0}f(h)g(h)=k$.

The last equality is correct whenever both limits exist (and are real numbers).

Comment: You could also mention that the limit of product is not the product of limits necessarily.

Comment: But it is, when all limits involved exist.

Comment: Rushabh Mehta is nonetheless correct, as was Vasya's comment above, and three of the other answers:  *the limit of the product is not necessarily the product of the limit*, particularly, it is not when the limit of one or both of the factors does not exist.

Comment: So to summarize, a limit can be distributed among its products ONLY if each of  those limits exist?

Comment: @ShootinLemons Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\infty$ isn’t a defined value - it’s indeterminate.

> $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\cdot g(x) = \lim_{x\to a}f(x)\cdot \lim_{x\to a}g(x) \text{   when both limits exist and are defined.}$$

In your case, you used the following limit: $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{h} = \infty$$

Since it doesn’t reach a finite, defined value, it is not applicable here.

In the second example, the limit was correctly broken down.

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(x+h)\cdot(f(x+h)-f(x))}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}g(x+h)\cdot\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$

Both limits are defined here, so this is correct. As $h \to 0$, the first limit approaches $g(x)$ and the second limit approaches the derivative of $f(x)$, or $f’(x)$. Therefore, the limit was correctly simplified, reaching $g(x)\cdot f’(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is a clear and precise understanding of algebra of limits. The product rule of limits is generally proved in the textbooks with an assumption that the limits of both factors exist. It can be extended to the case when limit of one of the factors exists and is *non-zero*. Unfortunately neither the usual nor the extended version of product rule applies here as one of the factors tends to $0$ and the other factor has no limit. Hence the application of product rule in your first example is wrong.

In the second example limits of both the factors exist and hence the usual product rule can be applied.